# virtualbox: How to change the place of controls in fullscreen mode

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to move controls (https://skitch.com/otarasenko/rqepn/xp-running) to the top of the Guest machine in fullscreen mode. how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings > General > Advanced > Mini ToolBar: Show At Top Of Screen

Answer (score 0):

2018 called - in VirtualBox 5.2 this checkbox moved under: `Settings > User Interface > Mini Toolbar > Show At Top Of Screen`